# How to inject different dependencies into WebApi Controller using StructureMap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap, asp.net-web-api

Currently I have an MVC application which also contains WebApi controllers.

I've set-up StructureMap to initialize using default conventions which handles service dependencies for both MVC and WebApi.  This all works perfectly.

However, I have one Authentication service dependency which should be injected for WebApi and a different implementation for MVC.  Since StructureMap has the same initialization bootstrap code, how do I switch depending on whether the request coming in is a WebApi endpoint or and Mvc controller endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is the best way of achieving this but I use the ObjectFactory.Configure method to override the initialization registries on boot-up but do this inside each SetResolver on Mvc's  DependencyResolver.SetResolver and on WebApi's GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver.SetResolver.

e.g.

```
 ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.For<IAuthenticationService>() 
                        .Use(s => s.GetInstance<IMvcAuthenticationService>()));
```

and

```
 ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.For<IAuthenticationService>() 
                        .Use(s => s.GetInstance<IWebApiAuthenticationService>()));
```